# Need a hand with a grep word command

Tags: grep

Just getting the hang of Linux Command Line, but having trouble with grep commands.

I'm trying to find out how many times a word appears in the last 1000 lines of a text file

I have a feeling that I need to use grep and pipes but can't figure it out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want to count the number of occurrences, but the number of matching lines, use @heemayl's answer. However, if you want to count each occurrence (so, count `word foo word` as 2 hits, not one), you can do:

```
tail -1000 file | grep -o word | wc -l
```

The `tail` command prints the last 1000 lines, the `grep -o word` searches for `word` and prints each case found (so it will print it twice if it matches twice) and `wc -l` counts the number of lines returned.

Alternatively, you could use something like perl to do the counting:

```
tail -n 1000 file | perl -alne '$k+=grep{/word/} @F; END{print $k}'
```

Finally, note that this will also count things like `wordsmith`. To match only if your pattern forms an entire word, use `grep` with the `-w` flag:

```
tail -1000 file | grep -wo word | wc -l
```

or

```
tail -n 1000 file | perl -alne '$k+=grep{/\bword\b/} @F; END{print $k}'
```

Comment: Thank you everyone!
I think this one works the best for what I want to achieve
"tail -1000 file | grep -wo word | wc -l"
as this counts the specific word and not other words it could be in.
I believe this also achieves the same result?
"tail -1000 file | grep -wc word"

Comment: @6rxobrut no, `tail -1000 file | grep -wc word` will count `word word` as one, not two. The `-c` option counts matching _lines_ not occurrences.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general pattern:

```
tail -1000 file.txt | grep -c "word"
```

This will print the number of lines that contain the pattern "word" in the last 1000 lines of the file named `file.txt`. Here we have used `tail -1000` to get the last 1000 lines of the file and then just used `grep -c` to count for the occurrences of the pattern in those lines.